# Contiki-NG Cooja simulator fails to start

Tags: cooja, contiki-ng

I have installed Contiki-NG on Ubuntu VMware Player and have been struggling to run it using `ant run` command following is the whole terminal code:

```
layla@ubuntu:~/contiki-ng/tools/cooja$ ant run
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I tried searching in the github repo for a solution, but got nothing similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cooja switched to Gradle as the build system. The documentation for the develop branch is available here: https://docs.contiki-ng.org/en/develop/

```
$ cd tools/cooja
$ ./gradlew run
```